# How to assign complicated regex to php variable

Tags: php, regex

first question in a long while! I need to find any and all urls's in a string returned from a facebook page request (I'm requesting the website of a page using the graphi api) and putting the value into an array that I subsequently display in a datatable js table.

Anyhow, I'm having issues as when I build the json data for the datatable, it breaks in some cases:-

http://socialinsightlab.com/datatable_fpages.json

The issue is with the website field having erroneous characters / structure / white space etc in the field.

Anyhow I found the perfect regex to use to find all websites in the field (there can be more than one website listed in the return).

The regex is

```
(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

When I try and assign it to a php variable as in preg_match_all I can't as it won't accept the regex string into the variable as it has quotes in it I guess.

So my question is how can I extract only the urls found in the website field and then assign them to a variable so i can add them to the datatable.

Here is an example of a call that fails:-

http://socialinsightlab.com/datatable_fpages.json

I need to be able to just return websites and nothing more.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Jonathan

Comment: So your real question is: "how do I assign a string to a variable that contains quote chars?"? Please show the code line in which you try to do that. Thanks.

Comment: add delimiters, escape quotes - there shouldn't be a problem with that RegEx.

Comment: And tell the data source, that if they want to publish JSON data it should be valid JSON data

Comment: I'm creating the json file but sometimes there is a field (website) from facebook that has multiple websites in the field, quotes, strange characters etc) so I am trying to just extract valid url's from the field but I can't even assign the regex (which I know works as I've tested in a regex emulator) to a variable so that I can run a preg match all :- $myregis = "(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))";

Comment: I think you are referring to such value `"www.trademediapromotion.com
coming soon ... very soon !!!"`? Am I right?

Comment: yep - exactly - I need to somehow catch and correct this - just extract the url

Comment: here's another example that breaks the json structure:-  ["68534853639","BMW X1","www.bmw.com/x1
    www.twitter.com / bmwx1
    www.youtube.com / TheNewBMWX1 ","
    71, 662 "],["
    125740330777403 ","
    BMW - AGMC Dubai ","
    www.bmw - dubai.com ","
    68, 512 "]

Comment: you should [edit] your question when you add extra information

Comment: For this specific job you can use this regex that matches them and all other URLs starting with `http(s)://www` or `www` but not websites like `bmwoforlandpark.com` that don't start with those delimiters: [**`(?:https?:\/\/(?:www)?|www)[^"\s]+`**](https://www.regex101.com/r/mX5X26/1)

Comment: thanks revo - it almost works - here's an example where it doesn't however - any ideas? http://rubular.com/r/rnNNiwv5Ku

Comment: It works actually those highlights are not continiuos if you mean it http://rubular.com/r/ofXiUJIaUZ

Comment: Hi Revo please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it please - I had to encapsulate the whole regex in the tilde character so it would work in php $myregex = '~(?:https?:\/\/(?:www)?|www)[^"\s]+~'; but it worked - thanks so much!

Comment: @revo, please post your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This regex is specifically made as a solution to this problem:

```
(?:https?:\/\/|www)[^"\s]+
```

**[Live demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/mX5X26/2)**

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to deal with all this quotes escaping, you can do the following:

1. Save regex to a file, say, `regex.txt`.
2. Read this file into variable and trim: `$regex = trim(file_get_contents("regex.txt"));`
3. Use it with `preg_match()` etc.